# Upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04, re-activation of 3rd party sources, login doesn't show up

Tags: 14.04, unity, upgrade, login, login-screen

I've just upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04. It went all fine, also the restart. Then, I re-activated some third party packages sources, and I did some updates. Afterwards, ubuntu doesn't start. The screen with "ubuntu" and some points below it appears. Then, the system freezes before I can see the login screen. I can manage to get into a terminal environment by pressing CTRL+ALT+F1 before it freezes.

I have removed all third party software, and I reinstalled unity, and the desktop environment. It didn't help.

Furter, I tried

```
unity --replace
```

giving

```
WARNING: no DISPLAY variable set, setting it to :0
stop: Unknown job: unity-panel-service
start: Unknown job: unity-panel-service
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: core
compiz (core) - Fatal: Couldn't open display :0
compiz (core) - Info: Stopping plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Unloading plugin: core

sudo lspci -vnn |grep VGA -A 12
```

gives

```
VGA compatible controler [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV710/M92 [Mobility Radeon HD 4350/4550] [1002:9555] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1471]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 49
Memory at c0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
I/O ports at 4000 [size=256]
Memory at d4400000 (32-bit, nonprefetchable) [size=64K]
Expansion ROM at d4420000 [disabled] [size=128K]
Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [58] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00 
Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
Kernel driver in use: radeon
Kernel modules: radeon
```

And trying

```
startx
```

gives

```
X: cannot stat /ets/X11/X (No such file or directory), aborting 
xinit: giving up 
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused 
xinit: server error What does that mean?
```

I highly appreciate any help!

Thanks.

Comment: Can you start the GUI manually using `startx`?

Comment: Not in the comments! Edit the question to add command output and errors, please!